# I added a Secure output in SSH session

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I've got a server running Linux. There is a web application running in this server. And I'm trying to view log using command

```
tail -f /path/to/file.log
```

The problem is that my Terminal window is 80x24 and when I can only see the last 24 lines of log. When I try to scroll up, there are empty line (everything is erased).

And when I logout, everything printed during SSH session to terminal is erased.

I realize that in some cases it is a useful security feature, however in my case I need to disable it. How can I do that?

**UPDATE:** I recorded video https://vid.me/wvZj

Comment: What kind of terminal are you using?  Regardless, if you run the `ssh` from something like `screen` or `tmux` you should be able to scroll and still see the output after exiting `ssh`

Comment: I think it's something server-specific because I use the same Terminal (build-in, Mac OS X) with other servers and it doesn't erase anything.

Comment: "alternate screen" might be involved: http://superuser.com/questions/136162/how-can-i-still-see-the-man-text-after-i-quit-man

Comment: May be you have a bash logout file on the remote server wich clean the terminal before logouting. –  netmonk

Comment: pipe the output through `cat -v` to stop the log using control chars to affect the terminal

Comment: I added video (see above)

Comment: What OS is the server running, and what ssh server?  Is it sending back curses output?

Answer (score 0):

You can just stream the file over SSH and print it locally on your terminal like so:

`ssh <server_user>@<server_address> 'tail -f /path/to/file.log'`

Or you can use a terminal multiplexer: `screen` or `tmux`. I use screen on a daily basis and it's a great tool. You SSH to a box, launch a screen session, do your stuff, then detach the session and log out from the server. Next time you SSH into that box you just run `screen -r` to reattach the session and you have the terminal in exactly the same state as you left it. Plus it has the option of scrolling the output.

Comment: Great suggestion, but the output erased anyway as soon as it goes out of the screen.

Comment: @AnthonyAnanich Alright, this is intruguing :) You mean even with `screen` the output is truncated when it goes off the screen? Have you tried tailing over SSH?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. And it only happens in this one server.

Comment: @Erathinel, I added video

Comment: @AnthonyAnanich OK, this is weird. We know this is server-specific but is it user-specific as well or does it happen to all users on that particualr server? What I mean to track is whether this could be something related to sshd_config or rather something in the user's RC files.